# Forbidden: 403 error aws Device Shadow REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-iam, iot, aws-iot-core

I use AWS IoT-core Device Shadow REST API I have created an IAM user role and give all access
this is my API key and header and endpoint

URL: {{endpoint-url}}/things/thingName/shadow

Method: GET

Header: header pass with AWS signature

accessKey: "accessKey"
secretKey: "secretKey"

execute-api working fine this is API response
[
{
"id": 1,
"type": "dog",
"price": 249.99
},
{
"id": 2,
"type": "cat",
"price": 124.99
},
{
"id": 3,
"type": "fish",
"price": 0.99
}
]

but my IoT-core Shadow REST API not working
I follow this docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-shadow-rest-api.html

attached screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/luBMa.png

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the solution was to set the `Service Name` field in Postman AWS Signature settings used to sign the AWS Signature V4 auth header to `iotdevicegateway` as per the docs here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot-data.html#IoTDataPlane.Client.get_thing_shadow

[image]